# Ruby Fog + Google Cloud Storage : signed URL from put_object_url generates InvalidPolicyDocument

Tags: ruby, google-cloud-storage, fog, fog-google

I currently use Google Cloud Storage with `paperclip` for image uploads. Everything works fine and my credentials are valid.

I now wish to generate a signed URL on Google Cloud Storage to give to users.

First I create a storage object:

```
storage = Fog::Storage.new(
        provider: "Google",
        google_storage_access_key_id: "KNOWN_GOOD_ID",
        google_storage_secret_access_key: "KNOWN_GOOD_KEY")
```

Then I create the URL:

```
storage.put_object_url("MY_BUCKET",
        "RANDOM_NAME.jpg",
        1.hour,
        'Content-Type' => 'image/jpeg')
```

Which return `https://storage.googleapis.com/MY_BUCKET/RANDOM_NAME.jpg?GoogleAccessId=REDACTED&Signature=REDACTED&Expires=3600`

In the past, if I temporarily enabled `AllUsers:W` (just temporarily!), I was able to POST a binary image (via Postman API client) to this bucket.

However, when I try to POST a jpeg file to the bucket now, I get this error:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<Error>
    <Code>InvalidPolicyDocument</Code>
    <Message>The content of the form does not meet the conditions specified in the policy document.</Message>
    <Details>Missing policy</Details>
</Error>
```

How do I resolve this `Missing policy` error?